# What are the technologies behind the http://itstimefor.skype.com

Tags: jquery, html, css

I really liked this site and I am wondering what technologies are behind this site? What I really would like to know is the dynamic movement of the elements on load (index page) and a constant flow between the pages. It seems that the pages are not loaded you just move from one place on one page to another.

Regards,

Comment: Right-click, View Source.

Comment: jQuery, JavaScript, HTML, CSS and little more

Comment: Tip: use [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/fx/?from=getfirefox), install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and have a look at the page itself, the CSS and what it does to elements, the scripts and the network activity of the page.  You could also use Chrome's built-in developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably just use javascript and a canvas element.

I've seen something like their menu before here on SO: http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/SQF6X/

*Don't know who made it, so I cannot give credit (but I think it is cool)*